# Creating a database table (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, create-table

I'm trying to create a database script that includes the SQL code for the following steps, and
execute each step using MySQL Workbench to  create and  populate a new table
called **recipe** in **fooddb.**

That recipe table should have columns for for the following object variables: **id (using   auto

increment), title, Instructions (just one string), numServings, and totalTime (in** 
minutes).

EDIT 3 - 11/4/2014 - 15:32... I may have figured it out, by I'm not too sure, however:

```
create table recipe ( 
RecipeID int not null auto_increment, 
'RecipeName' varchar(300), 
'RecipeType' varchar(100), 
"Instructions" text,
NumOfServings int not null,
TotalTimeInMinutes int not null,
primary key(RecipeID));

insert into recipe values (0, 'RecipeName', 'RecipeType', "Instructions", 0, 0); 

select * from recipe;
```

Is there anything that might be wrong with this?

Comment: If you need it in s/w development context you may consider Liquid Base instead of scripting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at the mysql manual to learn about creating databases/tables:

[Create Table Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table.html)

there are also examples of how to create tables.

**Edit:**
you can do either:

```
INSERT INTO recipe (name, category) VALUES ('Recipename', 'Categoryname');
```

since you only specify the columns where you want to add data

or

```
INSERT INTO recipe VALUES (0, 'Recipename', 'CategoryName');
```

because you have to give ALL data for all columns if you don't specify the columns.

Comment: I have taken your advice accordingly, as well as looked up other sources on how to tackle this more effectively. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

After testing my edited MySQL code in MySQL datbase, I can confirm that what I had typed up when testing it is correct.

This is mostly because I did some reading up on it and re - typing after encountering any and all errors.....